# height is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to build a little jQuery plugin, but im getting an error that group.height() is not a function?

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.equalHeight = function(group) {
        group = $.extend(group);

        var tallest = 0;
        group.each(function () {
            var thisHeight = $(this).height();
            if (thisHeight > tallest) {
                tallest = thisHeight;
            }
        });

        group.height(tallest);

        // allow jQuery chaining
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Usage example would be like this:

```
<script>
    // Usage example:
    $( ".boxes section.box" ).equalHeight();
</script>
```

Comment: $(this) is referencing the each loop rather than the selector

Comment: Use `group.each(function() { $(this).height(tallest); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.equalHeight = function () {
        var tallest = 0;
        this.each(function () {
            var thisHeight = $(this).height();
            if (thisHeight > tallest) {
                tallest = thisHeight;
            }
        });

        // allow jQuery chaining
        return this.height(tallest);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2w9WR/)

Comment: I think he wants to set the height, not get it

Comment: Sorry - my bad.  I see that now :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `this`?
In your declaration, your equalHeight takes a parameter, but you are not passing anything through. Note that in a custom jQuery function you don't have to pass in `group`, because the `this` identifier already refers to your group.

So, either do `group = this`, or replace it completely